# How to apply unocss rule when element has certain modifier class?

Tags: unocss

I have a HTML page where links sometimes have `router-link-active` class added by a third party library:

```html
<a href=".." class="text-red">Inactive link</a>
<a href=".." class="text-red router-link-active">Active link</a>
```

I want to style the links with unocss so that active links are blue instead of red. How do I do that? The proposed code would supposedly look like:

```html
<a href=".." class="text-red has-(.router-link-active):text-blue">Link</a>
```

generating the following CSS:

```css
has-\(\.router-link-active\)\:text-blue.router-link-active {
  color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the fuzz, I figured this:

```html
<a href=".." class="text-red [&.router-link-active]:text-blue">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could simply configure a `shortcut` in your config targeting the "external" class:

```
...,
shortcuts: [
    { 'router-link-active': 'text-blue' },
    ...
],
...
```